# JUnit tests fail after defining instance

Tags: java, junit, java-8

I've been trying to figure out how to work with JUnit but I've stumbled upon a problem I don't know how to fix.
I've written a class called OilTank that can take parameters long storedOil and long capacity with some other functions like getStoredOil() etc.
Now I'm trying to run some tests and without instantiating the class everything runs as expected.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class OilTankTest {

    @Test
    public void testIsValidStoredOil_InRange() {
        assertTrue(OilTank.isValidStoredOil(100, 150));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidStoredOil_TooHigh() {
        assertFalse(OilTank.isValidStoredOil(150, 100));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidStoredOil_Negative() {
        assertFalse(OilTank.isValidStoredOil(-100, 150));
    }
}
```

In this case my tests run fine and I get the expected result however when I try this:

```
...
class OilTankTest {

    OilTank tank_cap100_stored50;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        tank_cap100_stored50 = new OilTank(50,100);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidStoredOil_InRange() {
        assertTrue(OilTank.isValidStoredOil(100, 150));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidStoredOil_TooHigh() {
        assertFalse(OilTank.isValidStoredOil(150, 100));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidStoredOil_Negative() {
        assertFalse(OilTank.isValidStoredOil(-100, 150));
    }
    @Test
    public void testSetStoredOil_SingleCase() {
        tank_cap100_stored50.setStoredOil(97);
        assertEquals(97,tank_cap100_stored50.getStoredOil());
    }

}
```

all four tests fail. I would think at least the first three would succeed so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

EDIT: here's the code for the class OilTank.

```
public class OilTank {

    public OilTank(long storedOil, long capacity){
        assert isValidStoredOil(storedOil, this.getCapacity());
        assert isValidCapacity(capacity);
        this.storedOil = storedOil;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public long getStoredOil() {
        return this.storedOil;
    }

    public void setStoredOil(long storedOil) {
        assert isValidStoredOil(storedOil, this.getCapacity());
        this.storedOil = storedOil;
    }

    public static boolean isValidStoredOil(long storedOil, long capacity){
        return (storedOil >= 0) && (storedOil <= capacity);
    }

    private long storedOil;

    public static boolean isValidCapacity(long capacity) {
        return capacity > 0;
    }

    private final long capacity;
}
```

For the sake of completion the fail trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at OilTank.<init>(OilTank.java:31)
    at OilTankTest.setUp(OilTankTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$11(ClassTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$null$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the relevant code.

Comment: Please add the code of class `OilTank`

Comment: Why aren't you using the instance `tank_cap100_stored50` that you've created?

Comment: Forgot to paste in the test for which I needed the tank_cap100_stored50 instance. It's in there now.

Comment: What are the failure stack traces?

Comment: First line of constructor uses getter that hasn't been assigned yet so capacity is zdro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You OilTank constructor is using a getter to retrieve a value that hasn't been set

```
assert isValidStoredOil(storedOil, this.getCapacity());
```

Try using the variable passed in instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply that indeed fixed it. I have a couple of questions though. Why would using assert do anything even when my VM has no -ea parameter? And also, why would the other three tests suddenly be false when they don't use the called instance?

Comment: 2. they're failing on the `BeforeEach` because the constructor is b0rk

Comment: 1. I suspect eclipse is forcing -ea when you run jUnit tests (I don't use eclipse I just googled for that)

Comment: @JarneRenders `assert` shouldn’t be used to verify input parameters. Input parameter checks should be mandatory for `public` API members and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or similar. `assert` should be use to denote invariants. I recommend https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html